# how to grab rows with the current datetime -1

Tags: python

so i have this code:

```
def questions():
    day1 = day + dt.timedelta(days=-1)
    print(studydata_read.loc[studydata_read['Date'] == day1])
```

and i want to output any rows that have the date value of yesterday
(so if today was 8/11/2022 i want to grab all the rows with the date of 8/10/2022)
however i keep coming across this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\peter\Documents\coding\python\projects\In progress\Notesreview\notesreview.py", line 26, in <module>
    questions()
  File "c:\Users\peter\Documents\coding\python\projects\In progress\Notesreview\notesreview.py", line 15, in questions
    day1 = day + dt.timedelta(days=1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: `day` variable has string datatype you need to convert it to date for doing operation with timedelta

Comment: You need to transform day1 to a datetime object first.

Comment: `studydata_read['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(studydata_read['Date'])`